# How to decode user information from JWT Auth token - using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, token

I am getting user information from JWT Auth token in this way:

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": 5,
    "email": "shahzad@chiro.com",
    "status": 0,
    "created_at": "2019-04-12 07:33:28",
    "updated_at": "2019-04-12 07:33:28",
  }
}
```

and my controller:

```
public function getAuthenticatedUser()
{
    try {

        if (! $user = \Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
            return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
        }

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());

    }

    return response()->json(compact('user'));
}
```

but i want to also fetch additional information like from which module this user token is coming i want to proper validate this token, currently i have different modules like `Chiro`, `PT` and `ACCU`.
When i login user i got this information in JSON.

```
{
"status": true,
"message": "Login successfully",
"data": {
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9sb2NhbGhvc3RcL2ZlYXR1cmUtbWFzdGVyXC9hcGlcL2ZkX2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNTU1MDYzMTAzLCJleHAiOjE1ODY1OTkxMDMsIm5iZiI6MTU1NTA2MzEwMywianRpIjoiMFMxU3EzOVJRbVhYZFB6NCIsInN1YiI6NywicHJ2IjoiNGFjMDVjMGY4YWMwOGYzNjRjYjRkMDNmYjhlMWY2MzFmZWMzMjJlOCIsImFjY2Vzc19tb2R1bGUiOiJjaGlybyIsIm1vZHVsZV9pZCI6NiwidXNlcl9pZCI6N30.pJyWSlvHfJhn5bHk4_By-cAt5jzy15QgtlhGdyerriQ",
    "userData": {
        "id": 7,
        "email": "shahzad12@chiro.com",
        "status": 0,
        "created_at": "2019-04-12 09:58:01",
        "updated_at": "2019-04-12 09:58:01",
        "created_by": null,
        "updated_by": null,
        "is_super_admin": null,
        "basicInfo": null
    },
    "userInfo": {
        "id": 103,
        "user_id": 7,
        "clinic_name": "Health care",
        "first_name": "Dr wick",
        "middle_name": "john",
        "last_name": "David",
        "cell_phone_no": "111-111-1111",
        "phone_extension": 877,
        "doc_email": "nasir123@gmail.com",

    },
    "module": {
        "id": 6,
        "type": "Chiro",
        "slug": "chiro"
    },
```

When i login this response are saying this is user from `Chiro` module and when i validate this token using my method which i have shared it returns me only user email not the module.
How i can handle this situation when i validate token i should also get the module?
Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please consider editing your question and only include the code that is necessary to solve the problem. By now, in my opinion, your question is too specific. Try to generalize the problem

Comment: i am validating token and when i validate i got user information i just want additional information of user how i can do that?